# How do I install Net::Arping on CentOS 5?

Tags: linux, perl, centos, nagios

I have tried to install Net::Arping package using cpan and I can't do that because of errors...

```
CPAN.pm: Going to build R/RI/RIIKI/Net-Arping-0.02.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Net::Arping
cp Arping.pm blib/lib/Net/Arping.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap             /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/typemap  Arping.xs > Arping.xsc && mv Arping.xsc Arping.c
Please specify prototyping behavior for Arping.xs (see perlxs manual)
gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-    statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -    I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-    protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"0.02\" -    DXS_VERSION=\"0.02\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -    D_BSD_SOURCE -D__BSD_SOURCE -D__FAVOR_BSD -DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H Arping.c
Arping.xs: In function ‘XS_Net__Arping_send_arp’:
Arping.xs:116: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘libnet_name_resolve’
Arping.xs:124: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘libnet_select_device’ from incompatible     pointer type
Arping.xs:124: error: too many arguments to function ‘libnet_select_device’
Arping.xs:130: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘libnet_open_link_interface’
Arping.xs:130: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
Arping.xs:135: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘libnet_get_ipaddr’
Arping.xs:140: error: ‘LIBNET_IP_H’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Arping.xs:140: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Arping.xs:140: error: for each function it appears in.)
Arping.xs:143: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘libnet_init_packet’
Arping.xs:148: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘libnet_get_hwaddr’ from incompatible pointer type
Arping.xs:148: error: too many arguments to function ‘libnet_get_hwaddr’
Arping.xs:148: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
Arping.xs:156: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘libnet_build_ethernet’ from incompatible pointer type
Arping.xs:156: error: too few arguments to function ‘libnet_build_ethernet’
Arping.xs:161: warning: passing argument 12 of ‘libnet_build_arp’ from incompatible pointer type
Arping.xs:161: error: too few arguments to function ‘libnet_build_arp’
Arping.xs:166: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘pcap_open_live’ differ in signedness
Arping.xs:185: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘libnet_write_link_layer’
Arping.xs:196: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘libnet_close_link_interface’
Arping.xs:197: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘libnet_destroy_packet’
make: *** [Arping.o] Error 1
  /usr/bin/make  -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

I need this perl module for check_arping script for Nagios.

Some additional informations:

```
[root@atlantis build]# uname -a
Linux atlantis 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Apr 12 18:53:56 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@atlantis build]# rpm -qa | grep libnet
libnet-1.1.2.1-2.rf
[root@atlantis build]# rpm -qa | grep libpcap
libpcap-devel-0.9.4-15.el5
libpcap-0.9.4-15.el5
libpcap-0.9.4-15.el5
libpcap-devel-0.9.4-15.el5
[root@atlantis build]#
```

As You see I've installed libnet, libpcap and still there are problems ... Is anyone have an idea how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed libpcap-devel, but not libnet-devel. The *-devel version of an RPM includes C header files that are often required when building XS-based modules.

Try `sudo yum install libnet-devel` before trying to build the module again.

**Update:** The advice above was correct, but insufficient. I've just tested this on an installation of Centos 5.6 and it fails with exactly the same errors.

Looking at the [CPAN testers results](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/N/Net-Arping.html#Net-Arping-0.02), it's clear that version 0.02 of Net::Arping hasn't built successfully for anyone for a very long time. This distribution was uploaded to CPAN in 2002 and it appears that its XS code just isn't compatible with modern versions of libnet.

There is, however, on CPAN a [version 0.03 of Net::Arping](https://metacpan.org/release/RADEK/Net-Arping-0.03). This builds successfully on my Centos 5.6. I suggest you switch to using that instead. I haven't yet worked out why `cpan` doesn't recognise version 0.03. I see it's by a different author, so it might be a permissions problem. You should consider reporting this issue to modules@cpan.org.

Comment: `No package libnet-devel available.`

I was looking for it but I don't have it ... it's not in RPMFORGE for CentOS 5

Comment: It's in the EPEL repository. Which is the same place as libnet, so it looks like you have that repo configured. Do you have a file at `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`?

Comment: I have checked EPEL repository, I've installed both libnet and libnet-devel and libnet10 and libnet10-devel but still cpan/manuall compile not working.

Comment: After Update of You I've checked it, manually I have done:
`cpan> install R/RA/RADEK/Net-Arping-0.03.tar.gz`
and it started working as should be.
Thx alot davorg